# AngularJS 1.4.3 Routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Using AngularJS 1.4.3 I have tried to make a very basic routes and views and for some reason it works on my Plunker but not my laptop. I have tried running using a brackets server and a python server both give me this weird error please help. Error and Plunker of my very simple app below. Thanks in advance.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dqU7y4LITToz4wiL5orz?p=preview

Error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…20Ac.d%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A51233%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339)

app.js

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
          .when('/',{
              template: '<h1>Work</h1>'
          })
          .otherwise({ 
            template: '<h1>Not Found</h1>'
          });
    });

}());
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
         <ng-view></ng-view>
    </center>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: is this the actual code? if it is, the error is with the way you declared your `script` tag for `app.js`.  Script tags *are not* self closing, you must have `</script>`

Comment: use development version for more verbose error and stack trace output

Comment: Wow!  dam I completely spaced on seeing that very simple error.  Thank you very much. It works now on my laptop.

Comment: @Claies You should add this as a proper answer, so the OP can accept it and it can help other people with a similar problem.